# Move only 1 of two iterators in zip Python the first time

Tags: python, iterator, zip

I am reading two text files and want to iterate over them together. But one of them has headers on the first line which I want to skip. If I 'continue' after seeing the header line, both the iterators move ahead, and the data I want to compare in the files isn't aligned anymore.

What can I do so that I can skip the first line in one of the files and then start iterating over both?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you'd want to advance the iterator *before* passing to `zip`.  You can do this using the `next` builtin function:

```
header = next(file1)
for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('path/to/file/without/headers') as file1, open('path/to/file/with/headers') as file2:
    file2.readline()
    answer = zip(file1, file2)
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix `readline` and file iteration, since `readline` doesn't interact well with the iterator's buffering.

Comment: @user2357112: good point. Perhaps `next(file2)` might be better

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seek` method of file object for move to certain line:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm

For example:

```
for f in (file1, file2):
    if not is_header(f.readline()):
        f.seek(0)

lines = zip(file1, file2)
```

Just replace `is_header` to some check to define that line is header. In that case if first line is header iterator for this file would be in second position, otherwise it will be on first position, because we call `seek` method with position 0.